# Asset Depreciation - Logarithms

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, finance

How many years would it take for the value of a car purchased at 30 000 to fall to 15 000 if it depreciates by 15% in the first year and 12% every year after that?  This is not actually graded homework, but I solved it iteratively (compounding down to 26000 at 15% and so on) and would like to solve it using logarithms to find n as well.  The answer is 5 years based on the iterative method at which point it is 14800 or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us call $A$ the initial price, $B$ the price after $n$ years, $a$ the depreciation rate for the first year and $b$ the depreciation rate for the following years. When you built your formula, I suppose that you noticed the following relation
$$B = A (1-a) (1-b)^{n-1}$$.

So, going to logarithms is a very good way for finding $n$. For your example $A=30,000$, $B=15,000$,$a=0.15$,$b=0.12$ lead to $n=5.15094$.

It seems that, probably because of some rounding, we do not get exactly the same result

Comment: I am not sure that's correct.  Or perhaps my method was wrong.  I divided by 1.15 to get around 26000.  Does that seem okay?

Comment: @user124018. If the initial value is 30,000 and depreciation is 0.15, the value after one year is 30000 * (1-0.15)=25500. If you did the same for the other years, this explains that ! Cheers.

Comment: Ohh, I see, I think I calculated based on the calculation for present value, is that where the issue comes up?